# Scout import and algolia index

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

So basically I deployed my app to production, and I'm having an issue with Scout not importing the records.
in a component I have:

```
var algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
var client = algoliasearch('ID', 'KEY');
var = index = client.initIndex('prod_users'); // index i created in algolia with 0 records
```

my production database has 1 user
on my server I run

```
php artisan scout:import "App\User"
```

and it says:

```
Imported [App\User] models up to ID: 1
All [App\User] records have been imported
```

.

but when I look into my algolia dashboard in the indexes section, my prod_users index has 0 records

I don't know what i'm forgetting here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you pasted the API call of `php artisan scout:flush 'App\User'`.

You should probably check:

- your Algolia credentials in `.env`
- you index name in the `searchableAs()` method

Regards,

Comment: Well everything looks correct: in my .env I have SCOUT_DRIVER=algolia, ALGOLIA_APP_ID=ID, 
ALGOLIA_SECRET=KEY and my searchableAs() returns the correct index name..

Comment: The API call looks like a flush, not like an import. Is you website accessible?

Comment: you are right the API call i posted is a flush,but even from my local environement i can't scout:import, i don't understand why it doesn't go through to algolia

Comment: Do you mean that the API call doesn't go through? Can you see it in your Algolia Dashboard?

Comment: yes what is an import API call like? because i don't see it in the Algolia logs

Comment: This will be the same URL but the payload should be something like this:
```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "action": "addObject",
      "body": {
        "objectID": 2,
        "id": 2,
        "name": "fwergar",
        "email": "ergerg@fseg.com",
        "created_at": "2017-04-07 09:05:46",
        "updated_at": "2017-04-07 09:05:46"
      },
      "objectID": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you try this from your server? https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/search/#list-indices does it work?